# Unique Lock object per web request

Tags: c#, wcf, parallel-processing, locking

I'm building a WCF translation service. The service uses google translat's web api.
To avoid re-fetching commonly searched queries, the service keeps a memory cache of the last searches.
The search function first checks the cache, and only then puts out a request to google.
Last important detail - every time a request arrives, I construct a string to be it's key - it's comprised of the search term, and the two languages name codes - so it is unique per specific search.

The question is this:
Suppose two exact request's arrive at the same time, I would like to lock the second one out of the whole search function, so that when it enters it will find the search result that was already entered to the cache by the first one. If a different request arrives, I want to let it in.

My idea was to put a lock using the string I constructed, as it is unique per exact search (same search term, same languages). Will this give the result I described?

Thank for reading this far (:

See the code example below - and again thanks!

```
public async Task<TranslationResult> TranslateAsync(Langueges From, Langueges To, string Content)
{
   string key = Content + From.ToString() + To.ToString();
   lock(key)
   {
      //look for the search result in the cache
      //if not found, request from google and store result in the memory cache
   }
}
```

Comment: Lock on new string is obviously pointless, but when properly implemented this is reasonable approach if you ok with blocking all other threads. Consider if some for of asynchronous notification would do instead.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
// this cache is probably going to be the application level cache in asp.net
// but using Dictionary as an example in this case
Dictionary<string,TranslationResult> cache = new ...
private static object syncRoot = new Object();

if (!cache.ContainsKey(key)
{
    lock(syncRoot)
    {
        // this double checks is not a mistake.
        // the second request would check for existence of
        // the key once it acquire the lock
        if (!cache.ContainsKey(key) {
            // send request to google then store the result 
        }
        else {
            return cache[key];
        }
    }
}
else
{
    return cache[key];
}
```

Comment: You probably ask why can't you just use lock statement without the outer if statement. lock is very expensive compare to a simple check for existence. Your app's performance is gonna hurt without it considering it may get thousands of hit per day.

Comment: :) [Double checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) is harder than it looks - you are trying to read from dictionary that may be modified at the same time thus causing unexpected random errors.

Comment: @Tien-Dihn : Dictionary<Tkey,TValue> is not thread-safe: you could get a faulty read if you call ContainsKey() while another thread is adding an element where your code says "... then store the resul".

Comment: Oh as mention in my post, I'm using Dictionary a quick sample. The op mention he's going to cache for his entire web app so he's probably going to be using the asp.net Application state. Which I won't recommend but it his choice. Enterprise web app would probably use a database for the cache

Comment: Somewhat strange than why would you show sample code that *you know is not correct*.... Also sample is significantly worse than what OP is looking for - locking per unique key.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll get the behavior that you're looking for: the variable "key" will always be a newly created object and the current thread will always be granted the lock right away.  I don't believe string interning will be in play here because the "key" variable is not a literal.  If "key" were an interned string, then it might work like you want, but that would be a strange side-effect.

What to do?  Consider using the [ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677(v=vs.110).aspx) method.  Your "key" variable will become the key argument.  If the key is not in the cache, then the valueFactory will be called.  Your valuefactory implementation should send the call to Google.  This is ConcurrentDictionary is thread-safe, so no explicit locking is needed on your part.

Answer (score 0):

if two exact request's arrives at the same time then returns one of them with orginaly :)
You can know which is not trunslated then send it again. i made this before like this